# PostgreSQL Substring pattern with spaces

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, substring

I've been struggling with this query trying solutions found in this forum, but I can't go on. I need help.
I have a column that stores ship names througout the ship's life and I want to split them into three columns.
Mainly I have these three options,

a) Only one name

```
select t2.esp1,t2.espectro,t2.espectro1, t2.id from(
select substring(t.espectro, t.posfin)::varchar as esp1, t.espectro,t.espectro1,t.id from(
select "Id" as id, strpos(shipname, ', ') as posinic, strpos(shipname, ' y ') as posfin,shipname as espectro, shipname1 as espectro1 from ships) t)t2 (esp1, espectro, espectro1, id)
where t2.esp1 not like '% y %'`)
```

b) two names

```
select t2.esp1,t2.espectro,t2.espectro1, t2.id from(
select substring(t.espectro,1, t.posfin)::varchar as esp1, t.espectro,t.espectro1,t.id from(
select "Id" as id, strpos(shipname, ', ') as posinic, strpos(shipname ' y ') as posfin,shipname as espectro, shipname1 as espectro1 from ships) t)t2 (esp1, espectro, espectro1, id)
where t2.esp1 not like '%, %'`) and for the second name (`select t2.esp1,t2.espectro,t2.espectro1, t2.id from(
select substring(t.espectro, t.posfin)::varchar as esp2, t.espectro,t.espectro2,t.id from(
select "Id" as id, strpos(shipname, ', ') as posinic, strpos(shipname, ' y ') as posfin,shipname as espectro, shipname2 as espectro2 from ships) t)t2 (esp2, espectro, espectro2, id)
where t2.esp2 like '% y %' and t2.espectro not like '%, %';
```

and c) three names: I could get first

```
select substring(t.espectro,1,t.posicion) from(
select strpos(shipname, ',') as posicion,shipname as espectro from ships) t;` and third `select t2.esp3,t2.espectro,t2.espectro3, t2.id from(
select substring(t.espectro, t.posfin)::varchar as esp3, t.espectro,t.espectro3,t.id from(
select "Id" as id, strpos(shipname, ', ') as posinic, strpos(shipname, ' y ') as posfin,shipname as espectro, shipname3 as espectro3 from ships) t)t2 (esp3, espectro, espectro3, id)
where t2.esp3 like '% y %' and t2.espectro like '%, %';
```

but not second

The three named records look like this:

```
Nuestra Señora del Rosario, Santo Domingo y San José
```

I have tried this option:

```
select substring(t.shipsnames from '%#",_y#"%' for '#') as name2 from ships t
```

With several changes in the #"pattern#" to find the white spaces and get the second name.
Then I tried this option:

```
select t2.name2[6:7] from (regexp_split_to_array(t.shipnames, E'\\s+') as name2 from ships t) t2
```

But It doesn't work because not every record has the same length so some are solved like {"Santo","Domingo"} but other not like {"Rosario",","}.
I am not familiarized with regex sintax, I have found this example in the PostgreSQL documentation. Any hint?

Comment: Try `E'[\\s,]+'` if you need to split with both whitespace and commas.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? When `Nuestra Señora del Rosario, Santo Domingo y San José` is provided as input, do you want `Nuestra Señora del Rosario`, `Santo Domingo` and `San José` as output? If yes, one row with three separate columns or three rows with one column? Could you provide your solution for a) and b) as examples?

Comment: @markus-benko I added the code to substring the records I used. It worked fine. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: I want to achive three names separated in three different columns, because those are the three names that the ship got through its life. So, three columns name1, name2, name3 and store there each name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When names should be split whenever they are separated by *comma* plus optional whitespace or with an *y* surrounded by mandatory whitespace the following regular expression will work:

```
\s*,\s*|\s+y\s+
```

`\s`: whitespace character, `+`: at least one, `*`: zero or more and `|` means alternation.

Example SQL utilizing this regular expression:

```
SELECT Id, ShipNamesArray[1] ShipName1, ShipNamesArray[2] ShipName2, ShipNamesArray[3] ShipName3
FROM (
    SELECT Id, regexp_split_to_array(Shipnames, '\s*,\s*|\s+y\s+') ShipNamesArray
    FROM (VALUES
        (1, 'Nuestra Señora del Rosario, Santo Domingo y San José'),
        (2, 'Nuestra Señora del Rosario y Santo Domingo'),
        (3, 'Nuestra Señora del Rosario')
    ) AS ExampleShipNames (Id, ShipNames)
) AS SplitShipNames
```

The SQL will produce this output:

```
Id | ShipName1                  | ShipName2     | ShipName3
-- | -------------------------- | ------------- | ---------
 1 | Nuestra Señora del Rosario | Santo Domingo | San José
 2 | Nuestra Señora del Rosario | Santo Domingo |
 3 | Nuestra Señora del Rosario |               |
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the feedback. I tried your solution, and at least to me it fails.  It doesn't split the names between `\s+y\s+` and erases `s` characters. I have improved the code to this `'\,\s*|\s*y\s*'`. But now I have a new problem. There are some names like `Nuestra señora de los Reyes` or `San Cayetano` and those are splited to, because the code is not perfect. I have tried several options like `\,\s+|\s*y\s+` and other combinations. But It still doesn't work If there's no other solution, yours is great and needs only a bit cleaning work, so thanks in advance!

Comment: When you execute the SQL from the answer 1:1 as is, don't you get the expected output? What do you get instead? The regular expression doesn't erase s characters. Maybe there is a problem with copy and paste or a misunderstanding?

Comment: `Id|ShipName1|Shipname2|Shipname31|Nuestra Señora del Rosario| Santo Domingo y San José|""
2|Nuestra Señora del Rosario y Santo Domingo|""|""
3|Nuestra Señora del Rosario|""|""` This is the response I got. I'm using Postgres 8.3 in this server, may this be an issue?

Comment: Ok, so it works as I have expected, but unfortunately I must have completely misunderstood your question then. Can you explain with more detail what exactly is the input and what output you want to get, maybe by showing a *complete* example?

Comment: Hi! I don't think you have misunderstood the question, your expected output is what I exactly needed. The problem is that spanish names are tricky with lots of weird characters. Input is what I explained, a text field with names that most times are only one name, then two names separated by `' y '` and finally three names separated by `, ` and a `' y '` in the end. And I want to split this field in three separated fields, one for each name. As you proposed, it works, but `y` are tricky in spanish words like `Reyes, Cayetano, Rey, etc.` Thanks for the feedback.